# find last day of any weekday in month

Tags: php, excel, date, calendar

I am trying to determine if a given date is the last day of that type (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc.) in its month. For example, for March of 2016, the last Friday of the month is the 25th.

Please note I am not trying to figure out what the last day of the month is. Also, 'weekday' in the question refers to any of the 7 days, not just non-weekend days.

I am using excel and php as tags because I can work with either approach.

Comment: And how you tried to do this??? With formulas or VBA?

Comment: just formulas but I really have no idea where to start

Comment: Maybe PHP `echo date('m/d/y', strtotime('last monday of march'));`?

Comment: You will get a huge formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just determine how close the given date is to the end of the month.  For the given date in **A1**, use:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0)-A1<7,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I really couldn't find this anywhere. Hopefully someone else will find it more easily now!